# CSS/Jquery vertical menus with fixed place for submenu items

Tags: jquery, css, layout, menu

i have to design a full width page with the main_menu is on the starting left of the page..now each menu has different options which are to be shown when any item from the main_menu is selected, but in a div fixed for options...for e.g.

[image: the layout]

i.e. whenever someone chooses a menu_item from the main menu, the relevant options should be placed inside the container for options...

how can i do that?? can this be done using css only? or do i need to use jquery for it?

UPDATE --- check this out here////
http://jsfiddle.net/ybfrH/

Comment: well what i tried is,,,i created all the list options and put them in separate divs with a class that has display:none... now wrote my own jquery function to find which menu item was clicked, based on that i pulled the content from the relevant hidden div containing the options for that men_item, put display:block and put the content in the container for options.

Comment: You should add some code to your question, this will make it easier for you to find an answer, the more info you give the better.

Comment: I meant show us code so we can help you make it do what you want. Can't help if we have nothing to work with.

Comment: @ praveen please paste your code,you know, we can only guess if you don't.

Comment: if someone could come to teamviewer i could show everything i have done..pasting everything here could actually make the question too big!! and irritating...

Comment: Sorry pal ,Stack overflow is Q&A forum ,it is not meant to work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pure CSS3 Solution

This is not practical if you are wanting to support older browsers, as it uses the `:target` selector (which also means you are changing the `url` string when clicking main menu).

[**See the fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEHpr/4/).

**Given this HTML**

```
<div id="main-menu">
    <div class="center">
        <a id="p1" href="#opt1">Item 1</a>
        <a id="p2" href="#opt2">Item 2</a>
        <a id="p3" href="#opt3">Item 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="submenu">
    <div class="options">
        <div id="opt1">
            <a id="s1" href="#">Sub Item 1</a>
            <a id="s2" href="#">Sub Item 2</a>
            <a id="s3" href="#">Sub Item 3</a>
        </div>    
        <div id="opt2">
            <a id="s4" href="#">Sub Item 4</a>
            <a id="s5" href="#">Sub Item 5</a>
            <a id="s6" href="#">Sub Item 6</a>
        </div>        
        <div id="opt3">
            <a id="s7" href="#">Sub Item 7</a>
            <a id="s8" href="#">Sub Item 8</a>
            <a id="s9" href="#">Sub Item 9</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="application_area">
    <div id="header"></div>
</div>
```

**This CSS Does It** (the ***submenu is originally empty on page load*** with this--see below if desired otherwise)

```css
#submenu .options a {display: block;}
#submenu .options > div {display: none}

#submenu .options > div:target {
    display: block;
}
```

**To have Option 1 Show on Page Load**

First, move the `#opt1` div to be the ***last*** `div` of the `.options`, then use the following CSS instead of that given above ([**see the fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEHpr/11/)):

```css
#submenu .options a {display: block;}
.options > div:not(#opt1) {display: none}
.options > :target ~ #opt1 {display: none;}

#submenu .options > div:target {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: @praveen--that's good. If it is acceptable to you, then you should click the check mark just to the left of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using jquery  (i'm sure there are better ways to do this ,but here is one method)   [fiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/jathin/ZEHpr/)  ,

```
<body>

    <div id="main-menu">
        <div class="center">
            <p id="p1">Item 1</p>
            <p id="p2">Item 2</p>
            <p id="p3">Item 3</p>
             </div>
             </div>
            <div id="submenu">
            <div class="options">
           </div>
           </div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

     var opt = '<a href="#">Item 1</a></br>'+'<a href="#">Item 2</a></br>'+'<a  href="#">Item 3</a>';

     var opt2 = '<a href="#">Item 4</a></br>'+'<a href="#">Item 5</a></br>'+'<a href="#">Item 6</a>';

     var opt3 = '<a href="#">Item 7</a></br>'+'<a href="#">Item 8</a></br>'+'<a href="#">Item 9</a>';

        $("#p1").click(function(){

          $('.options').html(opt);

          });

       $("#p2").click(function(){

          $('.options').html(opt2);

          });

        $("#p3").click(function(){

          $('.options').html(opt3);

        });

    </script>

        </body>
```

Comment: but this is not a satisfying way of doing this...its like hard coding...anyway thanks for the solution..will use it somewhere else :)